# Why a Hermitian linear operator equal to its own complex conjugate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

I have been given the following definition for a Hermitian linear operator (HLO): 
A is a HLO, if $A=A^{H}$ such that $<Ax|y>=<x|A^{H} y>$.

Using this definition or otherwise, how can it be deduced that the operator is its own complex conjugate? 
Am I missing some underlying theory relating Hermitan conjugates and complex conjugates of LO's, when the LO acts on complex vector spaces?

Comment: The question came from something I saw earlier on today, which was along the following lines: If a Hermitian operator A is applied to a function in a complex vector space, say $f(x)$, $Af(x)$, and when then take the conjugate of this, we get: $A (f(x))^{*}$ ; for some reason the conjugate was not taken of $A$, and I don't understand why.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: Hermitian operators are, by definition, their own complex conjugate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Hermitian_operators.

Comment: A little confused on the downvote; anyone have any idea why? I'm new here, so if I'm violating some convention, let me know.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. The answer below is for Hermitian matrices (which is of course a Hermitian LO) , but in the sense of function spaces I don't think the transpose has any sense.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is: they're not, necessarily. There are two things that happen when you take the Hermitian conjugate: a transpose, and a complex conjugation. If you break down the Hermitian operators into symmetric and anti-symmetric parts, the symmetric part is real and the anti-symmetric part is imaginary. In equations:
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{let:}&\ A^\dagger = A,\ A_s \equiv \frac{A+A^T}{2},\ \mathrm{and}\ A_a \equiv \frac{A - A^T}{2} \Rightarrow \\
A_s^T = A_s & \Rightarrow A_s^\star = A_s \\
A_a^T = -A_a & \Rightarrow A_a^\star = -A_a.
\end{align}$$
You can also prioritize real and imaginary parts of $A$ to get:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{let:}&\ A_r \equiv \frac{A + A^\star}{2},\ \mathrm{and}\ A_i \equiv \frac{A - A^\star}{2} \Rightarrow \\
A_r^\star = A_r & \Rightarrow A_r^T = A_r \\
A_i^\star = -A_i & \Rightarrow A_i^T = -A_i.
\end{align}

You can add the $\langle y|$ and $|x\rangle$ to both sides of the above equations, and the conclusion won't be affected - that's just working in terms of the operator's matrix elements.

Comment: Is this not in a different sense, though? Would this (or a parallel) argument hold for an HLO acting on a Hilbert space? How would the 'breaking down' of 'matrices' in to their symmetric and skew-symmetric part work in this sense?

Comment: This works for any space where:
$$A^\dagger \equiv (A^\star)^T,$$
however those are defined. Consider the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$, where "transpose" is defined by integration by parts on functions that vanish at infinity. That function is antisymmetric, and only becomes Hermitian when multiplied by $i$.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is perfectly correct, it is also germane that in the algebras we're talking about we have $$\big(\langle x | y\rangle\big)^* = \langle y | x\rangle,$$ at the scalar level, and hence an operator which has the property you've specified must satisfy $$\big(\langle x | T ~y\rangle\big)^* = \langle y | T ~ x\rangle.$$ That basically is what it means to be your own conjugate transpose. To wit, if we have a basis $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|2\rangle,\dots\}$ for the space and define $T_{ij} = \langle i| T ~j\rangle$ then the above means that $$T_{ij}^* = T_{ji}.$$